# Context menus for nodes and edges for dot graphs using Python

Tags: python, contextmenu, graphviz, dot

Is there any easy way of adding context menus for nodes and edges for dot graphs using Python? Such that when clicking on a node or an edge, the context menu appears, the user can select a menu entry and then depending on the entry, Python code is executed?

Comment: Are you displaying a `Digraph` object? Are you using a Jupyter notebook or running as a script? I'm thinking of working on a solution using Tkinter, does that sound ok?

Comment: yes, a `Diagraph` object. I want to use a script. Tkinter sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any existing library that allowed arbitrary events for graphviz graphs - the closest I found was [xdot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py) which doesn't appear to fulfull your requirements.

So, I made something that should work for `graphviz.Digraph` objects.
The easiest way to display and register events on a graph I could find was to use JavaScript and export the graph to an SVG. I have used [pywebview](https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/) to run the HTML and JavaScript from Python without relying on a browser.

Apologies for all the JavaScript in an answer to a Python question, but this solution is intended to work for Python projects and JavaScript seemed to be the only viable approach.

This solution allows function callbacks to be attatched to both nodes and edges. The edges are quite thin making it hard to click on them, but it is possible, especially near the point of the arrow.

You can display the graph with the context menus using this code:

```
import graphviz


# import the code from the other file
import graphviz_context_menu

# create a simple graph
dot = graphviz.Digraph(comment='The Round Table', format='svg')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')


# display the graph
server = graphviz_context_menu.start_graph_server(
    dot,
    # the context menu for when a node is clicked
    node_menu={
        'Option 1': lambda node: print("option 1,", node, "clicked"),
        'Option 2': lambda node: print("option 2,", node, "clicked"),
    },
    # the context menu for when an edge is clicked
    edge_menu={
        "Edge Context Item": lambda edge: print("edge,", edge, "clicked"),
        "Another Edge Context Item": lambda edge: print("another,", edge, "clicked"),
        "Does nothing": lambda edge: None
    }
)
```

This relies upon another file in the same directory called `graphviz_context_menu.py` with these contents:

```
import webview
import re

js = """
const svg = document.querySelector("#graph > svg")
const nodeMenu = document.querySelector("#node_context_menu");
const edgeMenu = document.querySelector("#edge_context_menu");

const g = svg.childNodes[1];
let selected;

function addMenu(node, menu) {
    node.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => {
        menu.style.left = `${e.pageX}px`;
        menu.style.top = `${e.pageY}px`;

        selected = node.children[0].innerHTML;

        setMenuVisible(true, menu);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}

for(let node of g.childNodes) {
    if(node.tagName === "g"){
        const nodeClass = node.attributes.class.value;
        if(nodeClass === "node"){
            addMenu(node, nodeMenu);
        }
        if(nodeClass === "edge"){
            addMenu(node, edgeMenu);
        }
    }
}

function setMenuVisible(visible, menu) {
    if(visible) {
        setMenuVisible(false);
    }
    if(menu) {
        menu.style.display = visible ? "block" : "none";
    } else {
        setMenuVisible(visible, nodeMenu);
        setMenuVisible(visible, edgeMenu);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("click", e => {
    setMenuVisible(false);
});
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => {
    setMenuVisible(false);
    e.preventDefault();
});


function menuClick(menuType, item) {
    if(menuType === 'edge') {
        selected = selected.replace('&gt;','>');
    }
    pywebview.api.menu_item_clicked(menuType,selected,item);
}
"""

def make_menu(menu_info, menu_type):
    lis = '\n'.join(
        f'<li class="menu-option" onclick="menuClick(\'{menu_type}\', \'{name}\')">{name}</li>' for name in menu_info)
    return f"""
    <div class="menu" id="{menu_type}_context_menu">
      <ul class="menu-options">
        {lis}
      </ul>
    </div>
    """


style = """
.menu {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
.menu-options {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.menu-option {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-option:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
"""



def start_graph_server(graph, node_menu, edge_menu):
    svg = graph.pipe().decode()

    match = re.search(r'<svg width="(\d+)pt" height="(\d+)pt"', svg)
    width, height = match[1], match[2]

    html = f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                    <style>
                        {style}
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="graph">{svg}</div>
                    {make_menu(node_menu, 'node')}
                    {make_menu(edge_menu, 'edge')}
                    <script>{js}</script>
                </body>
                </html>
                """

    class Api:
        @staticmethod
        def menu_item_clicked(menu_type, selected, item):
            if menu_type == "node":
                callback = node_menu[item]
                callback(selected)
            elif menu_type == "edge":
                callback = edge_menu[item]
                callback(selected)
            return {}

    window = webview.create_window(
        "Graph Viewer",
        html=html,
        width=int(width) / 0.75 + 400, height=int(height) / 0.75 + 400,
        js_api=Api()
    )
    webview.start(args=window)
```

Comment: Many thanks! It was easy to run your solution, and it indeed provides the desired context menus. However, I do not like the need to use a browser so much. I will have a look into all those xdot forks.

Comment: @tillmo I've changed the solution so it creates a GUI window rather than using the browser. Is this better?

Comment: Many thanks, but I get `AttributeError: module webview has no attribute create_window`. I have webview-0.1.5-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: @tillmo I don't know exactly why you got that error - I just installed the module using `pip3 install pywebview` and it worked (tested on linux and windows).

Comment: ah, I had installed `webview`. With `pywebview`, it works. Many thanks! By the way: I also needed to `pip3 install` the modules `pyqt5` and `vext.gi`.